# Question about set of all functions and the power set of a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Hi so we know the set of all functions from a set X $\phi \rightarrow$ {0,1} create a one to one correspondence from the power set of X to the set of all functions but we are looking at certain subsets of the set of all functions. What if we look at the set of all permutation of a particular set X will it also be one to one correspondence with the power set ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends on whether the set if finite or infinite. If $X$ is finite, say with $n$ elements, then there are $n!$ permutations of $X$, but only $2^n$ subsets, and $n!>2^n$ for all $n\ge 3$. If $X$ is infinite, however, say of cardinality $\kappa$, then $X$ has $2^\kappa$ permutations and $2^\kappa$ subsets. There are $\kappa^\kappa=2^\kappa$ functions from $X$ to $X$, so $X$ has at most $2^\kappa$ permutations, and it’s not hard to produce $2^\kappa$ distinct permutations of $X$. (For example, we can use the fact that $\kappa+\kappa=\kappa$ to partition $X$ into $\kappa$ two-point sets. For each family $\mathscr{A}$ of these two-point sets we have the permutation of $X$ that interchanges the two elements in each $A\in\mathscr{A}$.) Note, though, that we’re using the axiom of choice in the discussion of infinite $X$.

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is finite with at least three elements, then the answer is no. There are $n!$ permutations but only $2^n$ subsets for a set of size $n$. And a simple induction argument shows that $2^n<n!$, for $n>2$.

For an infinite set this is true, but there is no "natural and explicit" bijection, since the proof is using the axiom of choice, and we cannot avoid it either.

Comment: Don't you mean for n>3? 8 is not less than 6.